# Crop raster plot in r

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am trying to read a hospital floor plan map (a higher resolution version than the one here in .PNG form) http://www.alfredicu.org.au/assets/Miscellaneous-Downloads/newicufloorplan.pdf

So that I can then place points onto it representing OHS incidents. My problem is that I need to be able to cut down the map so that I am only looking at a subset of the area so the x-axis (which represents mm of the A2 page) is 10:300 and the y axis is 10:380.

I have read in the array and plot but do not know how to subset this plot. If you can advise how to change the dimensions of the plot so that I can 'zoom in' on the relevant part of the map that would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Read PNG into raster array
r <- readPNG("ICU-map.png")

#Set up the plot area as A2 with mm as the dimensions
icu <-plot(0, type='n', main="ICU", xlab="x", ylab="y", xlim=c(0, 594), ylim=c(0, 420))

#Get the plot information so the image will fill the plot box, and draw it
lim <- par()
rasterImage(r, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
grid()
lines(c(1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0), c(1, 1.3, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 1.0),     type="b", lwd=5, col="white")
```

Comment: `plot(0, xlim=c(0, 594), ylim=c(0, 420))` 
`lim <- par()` `plot(0, type="n", xlim=c(10,300), ylim=c(10, 380), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")` `rasterImage(r, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])` meets your conditions ?